# Upload Multiple Image when code moved to another laptop it shows error

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

I did my best to debug this code in my first laptop and successfully worked it out but now when i move it to another laptop it suddenly began to show some errors again which i cannot understand the reason why.

Controller

```
public function uploadCollateralImage_Front()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/files';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2408';
    $config['max_width'] = '2408';
    $config['max_height'] = '2408';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile1')){
        $error = array('error'.'hey' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        var_dump( $error); die; 
    }else{
        $fileName = $this->upload->data();
        $post_image = $fileName['file_name'];
        // var_dump($post_image); die;
        return $post_image;
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php 
     $attributes = array('name' => 'applicationform');
     $hidden = array('userfile1' => 'userfile1');
     echo form_open_multipart("Client_Dashboard/applicationPost",$attributes, $hidden);
    ?>
```

Front-view Image

```
        <input type="file" name="userfile1" class="w3-margin-left w3-col s10 w3-teal w3-medium w3-hover-white w3-wide " required/>
```

and my main method

```
public function applicationPost(){
 $data_vehicleinformation = array();
 $data_vehicleinformation['FrontImage'] = $this->uploadCollateralImage_Front();
 check_insert_user = $this->foo_app->apply_loan($data_log, $data_user, 
 $data_loanapplication, $data_collateraldetails_app, $data_vehicleinformation , 
 $data_paymentdetails, $data_loanpayment, $data_loanapproval, 
 $data_loanrequest); 
}
```

it show some error like

array(1) { ["errorhey"]=> string(43) "
You did not select a file to upload.
" }
which totally means it did not end up saving in database. and i thought that my DB is the error maybe because of the collation or what other matter but its not it only show the error from function uploadCollateralImage()

Comment: Can you provide as much information about the two environments as possible. What PHP version on each, OS, apache, etc.

Comment: Make sure /uploads/files directory is there on new computer, it might cause problem if it is not already there

Comment: the whole system was cloned to another so im sure it has.

Comment: @HanthonyTagam what do you mean by whole system? You need to provide all the information on the PHP, apache, OS and more.

Comment: from PHP Version 5.6.23-windows8 to PHP Version 5.5.11-Windows7 Ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as by your comment:

> moved CI installation from PHP Version 5.6.23-windows8 to **PHP Version
>   5.5.11**-Windows7 Ultimate

the Codeigniter 3.x manual says:

> Server Requirements
>
> **PHP version 5.6 or newer** is recommended.

please check all server requirements [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/requirements.html#server-requirements)